# How to debug an OpenWisk processCallback action?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

How to determine what's not tying up properly?

All the debug sequences generated by `./bluepic.sh --install` *do* work with the exception of `bluepic/processCallback` - but it is not clear to me what are the correct arguments to this `wsk`.

The log  complains that `bluepic/processCallback` is

```
Unable to convert value of type Optional<protocol<>>: 
file Foundation/NSSwiftRuntime.swift, line 269
```

`local.env` says

```
 # Kitura server
 export KITURA_host="barneyrt.mybluemix.net"
 export KITURA_port=80
 export KITURA_schema="http://"
```

Tags and weather are written to the Cloudant data when the debug sequences are invoked.

## Further detail

After having updated all the credentials in `local.env` I have created the following actions:

```
    [@Iains-MacBook BluePic-OpenWhisk]$ ./bluepic.sh --reinstall
    ...
    Install Complete
    entities in namespace: iainhouston_blupicdev
    packages
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic                                    private
    actions
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processCallback                    private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processFinalWrite                  private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestThroughReadUser      private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestToReadImage          private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestThroughReadImage     private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestToWeather            private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestThroughWeather       private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestThroughAlchemy       private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestToCloudantWrite      private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processRequestThroughCloudantWrite private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processImage                       private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/kituraCallback                     private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/kituraRequestAuth                  private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/processImageStub                   private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/cloudantWrite                      private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/cloudantRead                       private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/alchemy                            private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/weather                            private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/httpGet                            private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/prepareCloudantWrite               private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/prepareWeatherRequest              private
    /iainhouston_blupicdev/bluepic/prepareReadImage                   private
    triggers
    rules
```

... and deployed the app to Bluemix and waited until the server app had restarted.

If I do `wsk action invoke processImage -p imageId 2f2bab3c3faad4e832d7a02bbf857b96` where `2f2bab3c3faad4e832d7a02bbf857b96` was the `_id` value of the image I found in the Cloudant database after having uploaded it via the Bluepic app, I get the `resource does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% certain that the issue is the quotes around the host name.  For example, mine is: `export KITURA_host=bluepic-unhypnotisable-urbiculture.mybluemix.net`

I'm in the process of rewriting the sequence into an orchestrator action using the `Whisk.invoke` API, which will make returning useful error messages a little easier.